# Страницы перестали открываться после установки permalink на %postname%

Tags: wordpress, utf-8, кириллица, http-status-code-404

Cайт WP на локальном сервере Apache (Ubuntu). Cтраницы перестали открываться (ошибка 404) после установки permalink на %postname%. Думал проблема в транслитерации и установил плагин Cyr-To-Lat, но это не помогло. Подскажите плиз как решить проблему. Спасибо!

**Обновление**

Я включил `mod_rewrite`, проверил в корне сайта файл `.htaccess`, его там не оказалось. Тогда я создал свой .htaccess и вставил туда код, который сгенерировал WP после установки

```
%postname%: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /wordpress/ RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L] </IfModule>
```

Но в результате, весь сайт перестал открываться :-(

Answer (score 1):

Стоит проверить включен ли mod_rewrite, есть ли в корне сайта файл .htaccess и есть ли у wordpress права на запись в него.

**Обновление**

Попробуйте иначе: создайте пустой `.htaccess` (ничего в него  не копируйте), затем зайдите в настройки ссылок вордпресс, верните значение к дефолтному, сохраните. Затем задайте своё правило (с `%postname%`) и снова сохраните

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: После проделанного тема моего сайта оказалась каким-то образром в корзине (вот почему весь сайт не открывался). Прошлось ее восстанавливать. Второй способ тоже не привел ни каким результатам. Увы.